# Programming to an interface - avoiding the later cast

Tags: java, interface

So, as I understand, one should always program to an interface, as in:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

So, later in my program I have:

```
public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
    return list;
}

public void processIntegers() {
    // I need an arraylist here
    ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>) getIntegers(); // can I do this better, without a cast?
}
```

Can I follow a better pattern here or somehow do something to avoid the cast? Casting seems very ugly in this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: i would also ask why this is better then using all the time a arrayList if in the end a cast is unavoidable.

Comment: @dontcare So you can pass this list of integers to a generic function that just accepts a list, not specifically an arraylist.

Comment: you should program to the least specific type you can get away with and no further.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an **Interface** - using a super class is an  _interface_ if you use it polymorphically.

Comment: @jsn: if it will accept a List, it will accept an ArrayList.  One of the great things about inheritance (at least in Java; I'm not familiar enough with other languages to know if it works) is that an instance of a subclass is automatically considered a member of the superclass, or the interface which it implements.  Therefore, an ArrayList is a List, and passing it to a function that accepts a List will be equivalent to casting it to List beforehand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all ask yourself a question: *why do you need an `ArrayList`*? Furthermore, should the clients of your API care about it? You have few choices:

- make `getIntegers()` return `ArrayList<Integer>`. It's not a crime
- Consider less strong interface requirement, e.g. `AbstractList` as a consensus
- Create a defensive copy so that you can consume any `List`:

  ```
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(getIntegers());
  ```

  consider using `instanceof` operator to avoid unnecessary copy if `getIntegers()` is already an `ArrayList`.

In other words - there is no way to avoid this casting with your requirements and in elegant way.